# PSN wrongly claims multiple downloads

Tags: ps3, psn, playstation-plus

I am a gamer on PS3 in India, having a PS+ subscription. Now, I lent my ID and password to a friend(let's call him R), since PSN allows for a game to be downloaded on 2 PS3s at once.

The problem occurred when a second friend(let's call him S) wanted in. The PSN Game, Gaucamelee, was a game he wanted, and R hadn't even touched. So, this morning, S logged into my account. Both R and I were offline.

When he tried to download the game, he was given a message that the game is active on 2 PS3s, and cannot be downloaded on the third. This is false.

Also, when he tried to download another game (Bioshock Infinite), which hadn't been activated by either of us, he got the same message again. This time, on PSN, it said that the game had not been Purchased, but when he tried to download, BOOM. Activated on 2 systems, magically.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: Pretty sure sharing of PSN accounts is not allowed. Not sure if that makes this question about circumventing copy protection?

Comment: So I'm not supposed to be doing this? Well, we share Retail versions of games, why can't we do the same with Digital? Or are you telling me lending my disc to my friend is also not allowed?

Comment: You can't do it because you can't do it. It's not the intended use of the multiple activation system. Developer intent speculation is definitely off-topic.

Comment: Lending retail versions is technically a violation of the EULA. It's just unenforcable. It comes down to the fact that even with physical copies of the game, you don't buy the game itself. You buy the right to install it on your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There can only be two active systems per account on PSN. Also there are only so many times it can be force deactivated on the SONY site per year so be careful what you do. So you can only game-share with one friend at a time. If they want to be able to share your account it will have to take some corridenation and have to deactivate and reactivate when eachother wants to play that game. I wouldn't suggest this though. If your system goes then you could be out your account. Better off telling one of them too bad.

Answer (score 4):

You're limited by system activations, not per-game activations. Once your account has been activated on two different consoles, you can only play games owned by this account on these consoles, you can't "mix and match" games between an infinite number of consoles.

Comment: So R is going to have to deactivate his system so that S can play?